# System.AggregateException

Tags: c#, .net, repository, lifetime

My project worked correctly and suddenly I got this error message:

> "System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Restaurant.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository.IUnitOfWork Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: Restaurant.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork': Unable to resolve service for type 'Restaurant.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Restaurant.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'.)'InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Restaurant.DataAccess.Data.ApplicationDbContext' while attempting to activate 'Restaurant.DataAccess.Repository.UnitOfWork'."

I dont know what should I do?
this is my program.cs:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Restaurant.DataAccess.Data;
using Restaurant.DataAccess.Repository;
using Restaurant.DataAccess.Repository.IRepository;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(
    builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();//Registering CategoryRepository in our dependency injection container

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication(); ;

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();//for creating an API in razor project to retriev data in data table ,so we should add map controller in program.cs at first

app.Run();
```

I change lifetime for registering UnitOfwork in program.cs but I did not work

Comment: Not seeing anywhere here where you register the `Restaurant` services?

Comment: See if something changed with ApplicationDbContext. The UnitOfWork service is using this service and it is failing.